# 'Change resolution' in menu bar

Tags: display, resolution, menu-bar, system-settings

I just upgraded to Catalina with a new Mac... and am wondering if it is possible to change the screen resolution from within the menu bar?

[image]

I was sure I used to do something like this years ago in Snow Leopard or Lion or something, but I might be getting mixed up with the 'external displays' menu.

Is this possible or do I need to go into System Preferences each time?

Comment: Each time? How often do you need to change the resolution of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not awre of anything built-in to macOS that would do this, however there is a utility that will do this.

Though I have never used it myself it has been around for a long time and often comes up in MacInTouch discussions as a great utility: [SwitchResX.](https://www.madrau.com/)